# Auto Complete is not working when I take input type as number in Android

Tags: android

In my application I created auto complete field by using the below code

```
sugarVariety =  (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_sugarVariety);          
     String[] VARIETY = new String[]{ "118", "119",  "120", "121", "269",    "270",   "271",   "272",  "273",   "346",  "347",   "348", "349",    "350","351",   "352",   "353",    "354",   "355",  "356",  "357", "358",
                "359",  "360", "361", "345", "117",    "266",    "362",    "363",   "364",   "365",   "366",   "367",   "368",  "369",   "370",   "371",  "372",  "373",   "374",   "375",  "376",  "377",
                "378",    "379",    "380",   "239",    "240",   "241",   "242",   "114",  "230", "231",  "101",   "102",  "103", "104",  "108", "111",  "112",  "201",  "202",  "204",  "206",   "207",
                 "208",    "210",   "217",   "218",   "220",  "221",   "226",   "227",  "250", "301",  "302","113", "228",  "0", "246", "999", "205",   "251", "243","268","329", "115", "116", "274"};
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, VARIETY);
     sugarVariety.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And in my layout I defined autocomplete textview as

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autocomplete_sugarVariety"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_height="42px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
```

The problem is if I give **inputType="number"** I am not getting AutoComplete list of numbers for the array if I remove it then only I am getting but in my case I want to show the keyboard with numbers only and also I need auto complete can any one tell me how can I get this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guy, you're doing something strange.

In your case you can cast all to String. If necessary get number after, you cast to `INT` or `LONG` again. 
(JUMP rs)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for reply but i am not getting what you says can you give some small snippet for me

Comment: Hi,It's working for me actually in simulator i am unable to see auto complete but in device it's working fine...

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is setting `String` array to `AutoCompleteTextView` of input type `number`.

So by changing `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayAdapter<Integer>` will solve this problem.

```
sugarVariety =  (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_sugarVariety);          
Integer[] VARIETY = new Integer[]{ 118, 119, 120, 121, 269, 270};
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, VARIETY);
sugarVariety.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

add filterOptions property to autoComplete component

```
<Autocomplete
filterOptions={(options) => options}
```